# Unable to create logon script - Access denied?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, file-permissions

I'm currently trying to create a logon script that will map a few network drives for all users.

I've created the script, but when I try placing the .bat file in the proper folder, I get an "Access Denied" message.

I'm logged in locally on the server as a domain admin, and domain admins have full control of the folder.

The folder in question is `\\mydomain\sysvol\mydomain\Policies\{GUID}\User\Scripts`.

I get an access denied message when attempting to add my user account to the list (shouldn't have to anyway).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have UAC enabled, you need to copy the files from a privileged process.

Personally, I typically do not use the sysvol tree to store login scripts: a simple shared directory with properly configured ACL usually serves me much better.

Comment: Elavated command prompt did the trick for me. Thanks for pointing in the right direction. Usually it lets me press "Continue" and get the UAC prompt to copy things.

Comment: I use the legacy `netlogon` share because it's already part of a domain DFS root.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Quite odd behavior, I had to copy the script elsewhere, edit it, and copy it back to get the UAC "Continue as admin" prompt. One would think editing the file in place would trigger this same prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Some what of an old topic but I just ran in to this problem my self on a 2012 R2 server.

I was trying to add the script (bat file) to the folder on a domain controller that wasn't the PDC (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/197132).

Once I switched to the PDC I was able to copy the script in to the folder.